# what is the reason multiply default dispatcher threads

Tags: scala, akka

looking at my threads (using jconsole) I see a lot of dispatchers :

```
akka.actor.default-dispatcher-...
```

however I am not creating the Actors withDispatcher. what can be the reason for multiply dispatcher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> Every ActorSystem will have a default dispatcher that will be used in
>   case nothing else is configured for an Actor.

What you see in jconsole are the threads currently submitted to the default dispatcher. These take the name of `default-dispatcher-1`, `default-dispatcher-2`, etc. They are all run by the same unique, default-dispatcher.

The `withDispatcher` call allows you to specify multiple dispatchers - different from the default one.

More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html).